# What's the difference between dir/* , dir/**, dir/**/* , dir/**/*.* in globbing?

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

Imagine the following directory structure:

```
web/
  sub1/
    1.js
  3.js
```

When I use 'del' node module to delete file or directory, the behavior of 
`dir/* , dir/**, dir/**/*, dir/**/*.*` is different.

```
web/*
```

del(['`web/*`', '!web/sub1/1.js'])
-> everything under web/ is removed, web/sub1/1.js is removed as well
del(['`web/*`', '!web/3.js']})
-> everything under web/ is removed except 3.js is keeped

```
web/**
```

del(['`web/**`', '!web/sub1/1.js']), del(['`web/**`', '!web/3.js'])
-> the result of the two forms are the same, web/ is completely removed

```
web/**/*
```

del(['`web/**/*`', '!web/sub1/1.js'])
 -> everything under web/ is removed
 del(['`web/**/*`', '!web/3.js']})
 -> everything under web/ is removed except 3.js is keeped

```
web/**/*.*
```

del(['`web/**/*.*`', '!web/sub1/1.js'])
-> all files under web/ is removed except web/sub/1.js and the directory   structure is keeped
del(['`web/**/*.*`', '!web/3.js']})
-> all files under web/ is removed except 3.js and the directory structure is keeped

After done the above test, I'm totally confused, I can't summarize a rule out of the above test. And I can't find some detailed documentation explaining these.
Can someone help here??

Answer (score 0):

node [del](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del) uses [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for matching targets and [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) for removing matched targets. All matched targets will be passed to rimraf and rimraf will remove file or will remove directory recursively. So an answer to your question is what targets are matched by your patterns.

> web/*

All child items are matched: `web/sub1`, `web/3.js`. All will be removed, `!web/sub1/1.js` does not exclude anything. But `!web/3.js` excludes the file, so only `web/sub1` will be removed recursively.

> web/**

The directory and all nested items are matched: `web`, `web/sub1`, `web/sub1/1.js`, `web/3.js`. Because the directory will be removed recursively any files exclusions are not efficient.

> web/**/*

All nested items are matched: `web/sub1`, `web/sub1/1.js`, `web/3.js`. `web/sub1` will be removed recursively and exclusion `!web/sub1/1.js` does not matter. But exclusion `!web/3.js` keeps the file.

> web/**/*.*

Only nested files are matched: `web/sub1/1.js`, `web/3.js`. So no directories will be removed and exclusion of file keeps it.